# How to download/upload large text file to client-side app

Tags: javascript, html, file, stream

Im trying to download .obj file, that I generate client-side from binary array of vertexes. The problem is that there are too many vertexes to fit into browser window memory

```
exportOBJ() {
    var output = 'o object_export\n';
    var i, j, k, l, x, y, z;

    var vertices = this._vertices.array;

    for (i = 0; i < vertices.length; i += 3) {
        x = vertices[i];
        y = vertices[i + 1];
        z = vertices[i + 2];

        output += 'v ' + x + ' ' + y + ' ' + z + '\n';
    }

    //Other data...
}
```

//Saving method

```
    function (data) {

        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/obj;charset=utf-8;' });
        if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
            navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
        } else {
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
                // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
                var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.setAttribute("href", url);
                link.setAttribute("download", 'export.obj');
                link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            }
        }
    })
```

So this works fine with small vertex files, but when there are many vertexes, like 10M, browser window crashes.
I looked into using filestreams, but that is not client-side, as far as I understand.
Same goes for https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js  and I also require to be able to upload.

Answer (score 1):

In the github project mentioned in your question, it was mentioned that it works on client-side when your website runs on https. It uses man-in-the-middle strategy only when your website isn't https.

So, as long as your website is https, you can use the service worker to intercept the URL fetch requests, and download the content.

By the way, the project you mentioned is quite useful. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I will check it out again, I must have read it wrong, although I will still have upload issue, even if it works.